# trouble with Cantera install with old(?) Python3 module on Debian Testing to run a SCons script

Tags: python, python-3.x, debian, scons, cantera

**UPDATE**

Here is the link to cantera: [enter link description here](https://cantera.org/install/compiling-install.html)  and I do have scons installed;

```
 apt-cache policy scons*
  scons:
 Installed: 4.0.1+dfsg-2
 Candidate: 4.0.1+dfsg-2
 Version table:
 *** 4.0.1+dfsg-2 900
    900 http://deb.debian.org/debian testing/main amd64 Packages
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.0.1-2 500
    500 http://http.us.debian.org/debian stable/main amd64 Packages
```

The direct link to the source:

[enter link description here](https://github.com/Cantera/cantera)

and here is a example of calling the install script;

`scons build prefix='/home/X/SW/Cantera/installed/'  --config=force`

---

I have been trying to upgrade/install Cantera (cantera.org), and it relies on Scons (the script, 'SConstruct' is used). I notice in the script it has a line, `from buildutils import *`. I tried to install it using, `python3 -m pip install --user buildutils`, but I get this big error:

```
2016|0|X@X ~/SW/Cantera/cantera $ Wed  7 04 2021, 13:24:08 
 python3 -m pip install --user buildutils
Collecting buildutils
  Using cached buildutils-0.3.tar.gz (47 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-v3fu4kdk/buildutils_3a844402d1bc49ec99a3331d798a6021/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-v3fu4kdk/buildutils_3a844402d1bc49ec99a3331d798a6021/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-owjzbfid
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-v3fu4kdk/buildutils_3a844402d1bc49ec99a3331d798a6021/
    Complete output (8 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-v3fu4kdk/buildutils_3a844402d1bc49ec99a3331d798a6021/setup.py", line 5, in <module>
        from ez_setup import use_setuptools
      File "/tmp/pip-install-v3fu4kdk/buildutils_3a844402d1bc49ec99a3331d798a6021/ez_setup.py", line 91
        except pkg_resources.VersionConflict, e:
                                            ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b2/84/797607896d265c2bf00cdaff35c901713f738dfc4efe8ee23bdedb42c789/buildutils-0.3.tar.gz#sha256=8f9921cf145a1879986b4028db0af4f028f65fe6eae29936490174037ba7dfc5 (from https://pypi.org/simple/buildutils/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  Using cached buildutils-0.1.2.tar.gz (42 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-v3fu4kdk/buildutils_861964493705449c937dc2face33fe7e/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-v3fu4kdk/buildutils_861964493705449c937dc2face33fe7e/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-28mf5gk7
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-v3fu4kdk/buildutils_861964493705449c937dc2face33fe7e/
    Complete output (8 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-v3fu4kdk/buildutils_861964493705449c937dc2face33fe7e/setup.py", line 5, in <module>
        from ez_setup import use_setuptools
      File "/tmp/pip-install-v3fu4kdk/buildutils_861964493705449c937dc2face33fe7e/ez_setup.py", line 160
        print "Setuptools successfully installed or upgraded."
              ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("Setuptools successfully installed or upgraded.")?
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding  https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d7/62/b25a56b638d9e1cfc08eba7fd0aa5876f3e2c86f30ca4c5b8c3cda2af524/buildutils-0.1.2.tar.gz#sha256=ad9d597e6836535010880128e5614145f84939c7e26a64c186a7eb37454fa8db (from https://pypi.org/simple/buildutils/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement buildutils
ERROR: No matching distribution found for buildutils
```

I see 'version conflict' and a problem with a parenthesis.... I also noticed that the latest release is from 2007...https://pypi.org/project/buildutils/ Is there a newer replacement for this?

I thought of trying to manually install it from source (the egg files were apparently built for python2), but was unable to successfully execute `ez_setup.py` or `setup.py` without errors.  I followed one page but having never done it before I'm not sure what happened.

I have seen many requests on the internet about modules not being found, but most of the answers revolve around misnaming it ([Can't install PyZMP for Python -- Dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22815673/cant-install-pyzmp-for-python-dependencies?r=SearchResults)), or it not being installed.

I search for somethign pertaining to `buildutils` from the Debian repo, but nothing relevant came up.

This originated from an error I got about `KeyValue` from the scons script, the relevant part here shown:

```
...
...
--------------------- end config.log ---------------------
INFO: Using NumPy version 1.19.5.
INFO: Using Cython version 0.29.21.
INFO: Building the full Python package for Python 3.9
KeyError: 'HAS_CLANG':
  File "/home/X/SW/Cantera/cantera/SConstruct", line 1543:
    if env['OS'] == 'Solaris' or env['HAS_CLANG']:
  File "/home/X/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/SCons/Environment.py", line 388:
    return self._dict[key]
```

So the lines around 1543, of the script `SConstruct`, are;

```
...
196 env = Environment(tools=toolchain+['textfile', 'subst', 'recursiveInstall', 'wix', 'gch'],
197                   ENV={'PATH': os.environ['PATH']},
198                   toolchain=toolchain,
199                   **extraEnvArgs)
200
201 env['OS'] = platform.system()
202 env['OS_BITS'] = int(platform.architecture()[0][:2])
...
825 conf = Configure(env, custom_tests={'CheckStatement': CheckStatement})
...
1032 env['HAS_CLANG'] = conf.CheckDeclaration('__clang__', '', 'C++')
...
1526
1527 configh = {}
1528
1529 configh['CANTERA_VERSION'] = quoted(env['cantera_version'])
1530 configh['CANTERA_SHORT_VERSION'] = quoted(env['cantera_short_version'])
1531
1532 # Conditional defines
1533 def cdefine(definevar, configvar, comp=True, value=1):
1534     if env.get(configvar) == comp:
1535         configh[definevar] = value
1536     else:
1537         configh[definevar] = None
1538
1539 # Need to test all of these to see what platform.system() returns
1540 configh['SOLARIS'] = 1 if env['OS'] == 'Solaris' else None
1541 configh['DARWIN'] = 1 if env['OS'] == 'Darwin' else None
1542
1543 if env['OS'] == 'Solaris' or env['HAS_CLANG']:
1544     configh['NEEDS_GENERIC_TEMPL_STATIC_DECL'] = 1
1545
1546 configh['CT_SUNDIALS_VERSION'] = env['sundials_version'].replace('.','')
1547
1548 if env.get('has_sundials_lapack') and env['use_lapack']:
1549     configh['CT_SUNDIALS_USE_LAPACK'] = 1
1550 else:
1551     configh['CT_SUNDIALS_USE_LAPACK'] = 0
1552
1553 cdefine('LAPACK_FTN_STRING_LEN_AT_END', 'lapack_ftn_string_len_at_end')
```

This looks simply like a dictionary, i.e. the **Quick Start** section here: [enter link description here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) but I cannot find a `def Environment` (maybe this Configure also) in the scripts in the directories (`grep -nRHI "def Environment" *`) so I assume it might be part of this module `buildutils`. This then explains why I tried to install it and the subsequent errors. I realize I could try to just comment out line 1543 and de-indent line 1544, as I do have clang, but I'm not sure if I have the 'right' clang...

**EDIT**

I do have `buildutil`, and searching PyPl, maybe this is the replacement.... the mercurial repository link for `buildutils` doesn't seem to work, but maybe I could just `awk` replace the names throughout the project... I also see though on [https://pypi.org/project/buildutil/](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) that it might only be good for python3.6...

**EDIT 2**

I now wonder if it isn't just a renaming..., as both names are listed on https://github.com/tedicreations/buildutil... so maybe just `awk` the script to change the name from `buildutils` to `buildutil`...

**EDIT 3**
Upon the suggestion of `2to3`, I tried it with these changes showing;

```
 2to3 -f all -w SConstruct
RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: buffer
RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: idioms
RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
RefactoringTool: Refactored SConstruct
--- SConstruct  (original)
+++ SConstruct  (refactored)
@@ -37,7 +37,7 @@
     'scons doxygen' - Build the Doxygen documentation
 """
 
-from __future__ import print_function
+
 from buildutils import *
 
 if not COMMAND_LINE_TARGETS:
@@ -216,7 +216,7 @@
 
 # Fix an issue with Unicode sneaking into the environment on Windows
 if os.name == 'nt':
-    for key,val in env['ENV'].items():
+    for key,val in list(env['ENV'].items()):
         env['ENV'][key] = str(val)
 
 if 'FRAMEWORKS' not in env:
@@ -327,7 +327,7 @@
 defaults.python_prefix = '$prefix' if env['OS'] != 'Windows' else ''
 
 # Transform lists into strings to keep cantera.conf clean
-for key,value in defaults.__dict__.items():
+for key,value in list(defaults.__dict__.items()):
     if isinstance(value, (list, tuple)):
         setattr(defaults, key, ' '.join(value))
 
@@ -660,7 +660,7 @@
 
 # Expand ~/ and environment variables used in cantera.conf (variables used on
 # the command line will be expanded by the shell)
-for option in opts.keys():
+for option in list(opts.keys()):
     original = env[option]
     if isinstance(original, str):
         modified = os.path.expandvars(os.path.expanduser(env[option]))
RefactoringTool: Files that were modified:
RefactoringTool: SConstruct
```

but after a `scons clean` and a `scons test-clean`, the error remains (maybe it is a dictionary problem...);

```
 scons build prefix='/home/X/SW/Cantera/installed/'  --config=force
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
INFO: SCons is using the following Python interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
Configuration variables read from 'cantera.conf' and command line:
    prefix = '/home/X/SW/Cantera/installed/'

Checking for C++ header file cmath... yes
Checking for C++ header file fmt/ostream.h... yes
INFO: Using system installation of fmt library.
INFO: Found fmt version 7.1.3
Checking for C++ header file yaml-cpp/yaml.h... yes
INFO: Using system installation of yaml-cpp library.
Checking for C++ header file gtest/gtest.h... no
Checking for C++ header file gmock/gmock.h... no
INFO: Using Googletest from Git submodule
Checking for C++ header file Eigen/Dense... no
INFO: Using private installation of Eigen.
INFO: Found Eigen version 3.3.7
Checking whether __GLIBCXX__ is declared... yes
Checking whether __clang__ is declared... no
Checking for C++ header file omp.h... yes
INFO: Found Boost version 1.74
Checking whether boost::core::demangle is declared... yes
Checking for CVodeCreate(CV_BDF, CV_NEWTON) in C++ library sundials_cvodes... no
Checking for CVodeCreate(CV_BDF) in C++ library sundials_cvodes... yes
Checking for double x; log(x) in C library None... no
INFO: Using system installation of Sundials version 4.1.0.
Checking whether SUNDIALS_BLAS_LAPACK is declared... yes
sh: 1: .sconf_temp/conftest_9d002cee8d847914673abd8559024f70_0_3ae94ee097a5c84b400a349871c73680: not found
WARNING: Unable to use 'gfortran' to compile the Fortran interface. See config.log for details.
INFO: Skipping compilation of the Fortran 90 interface.
INFO: Using NumPy version 1.19.5.
INFO: Using Cython version 0.29.21.
INFO: Building the full Python package for Python 3.9
KeyError: 'HAS_CLANG':
  File "/home/X/SW/Cantera/cantera/SConstruct", line 1542:
    if env['OS'] == 'Solaris' or env['HAS_CLANG']:
  File "/home/X/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/SCons/Environment.py", line 388:
    return self._dict[key]
```

I note that, the rules of `2to3` probably have no way of translating a module from `buildutils` to `buildutil`, if that is indeed an appropriate change...

and...

This is from `modernize` module, which, as it didn't get rid of `buildutils` (I don't have it), it seemed pointless to try and run it... I did... still same error.

```
 python3 -m modernize -w SConstruct 
 Loading the following fixers:
    fissix.fixes.fix_apply  (apply)
    fissix.fixes.fix_except  (except)
    fissix.fixes.fix_exec  (exec)
    fissix.fixes.fix_execfile  (execfile)
    fissix.fixes.fix_exitfunc  (exitfunc)
    fissix.fixes.fix_funcattrs  (funcattrs)
    fissix.fixes.fix_has_key  (has_key)
    fissix.fixes.fix_idioms  (idioms)
    fissix.fixes.fix_long  (long)
    fissix.fixes.fix_methodattrs  (methodattrs)
    fissix.fixes.fix_ne  (ne)
    fissix.fixes.fix_numliterals  (numliterals)
    fissix.fixes.fix_operator  (operator)
    fissix.fixes.fix_paren  (paren)
    fissix.fixes.fix_reduce  (reduce)
    fissix.fixes.fix_renames  (renames)
    fissix.fixes.fix_repr  (repr)
    fissix.fixes.fix_set_literal  (set_literal)
    fissix.fixes.fix_standarderror  (standarderror)
    fissix.fixes.fix_sys_exc  (sys_exc)
    fissix.fixes.fix_throw  (throw)
    fissix.fixes.fix_tuple_params  (tuple_params)
    fissix.fixes.fix_types  (types)
    fissix.fixes.fix_ws_comma  (ws_comma)
    fissix.fixes.fix_xreadlines  (xreadlines)
    libmodernize.fixes.fix_basestring  (basestring)
    libmodernize.fixes.fix_dict_six  (dict_six)
    libmodernize.fixes.fix_file  (file)
    libmodernize.fixes.fix_filter  (filter)
    libmodernize.fixes.fix_import  (import)
    libmodernize.fixes.fix_imports_six  (imports_six)
    libmodernize.fixes.fix_input_six  (input_six)
    libmodernize.fixes.fix_int_long_tuple  (int_long_tuple)
    libmodernize.fixes.fix_itertools_imports_six  (itertools_imports_six)
    libmodernize.fixes.fix_itertools_six  (itertools_six)
    libmodernize.fixes.fix_map  (map)
    libmodernize.fixes.fix_metaclass  (metaclass)
    libmodernize.fixes.fix_next  (next)
    libmodernize.fixes.fix_print  (print)
    libmodernize.fixes.fix_raise  (raise)
    libmodernize.fixes.fix_raise_six  (raise_six)
    libmodernize.fixes.fix_unichr  (unichr)
    libmodernize.fixes.fix_unicode_type  (unicode_type)
    libmodernize.fixes.fix_urllib_six  (urllib_six)
    libmodernize.fixes.fix_xrange_six  (xrange_six)
    libmodernize.fixes.fix_zip  (zip)
 Applying the following explicit transformations:
    (None)

RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: idioms
RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
RefactoringTool: Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
RefactoringTool: Refactored SConstruct
--- SConstruct  (original)
+++ SConstruct  (refactored)
@@ -38,6 +38,7 @@
 """
 
 from __future__ import print_function
+from __future__ import absolute_import
 from buildutils import *
 
 if not COMMAND_LINE_TARGETS:
RefactoringTool: Files that were modified:
RefactoringTool: SConstruct
```

Comment: Did you install SCons? I have no idea what buildutils is. Environment() is part of SCons.

Comment: Please add a link to the source repo for cantera? Do they have any instructions on how to build? If so please add a link to that as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Porting SConstruct to Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63752385/porting-sconstruct-to-python-3)

Comment: I missed that... it looks quite promising and I'll try it in a few hours...

Comment: It's kind of hard to follow this: but the configure step which sets HAS_CLANG apparently hasn't run or succeeded.  You can change the line a little bit so it doesn't fail if it's unset: `if env['OS'] == 'Solaris' or env.get('HAS_CLANG'):`  2to3 is aggressive about wrapping Py3's dict views in a list(), often not needed but don't worry about that for now.

Comment: Well that moved me on to the next error, the very next line 1546. Quickly tried the SCons manual with env.Replace(VAR='new') but I guess I'll have to learn SCons somewhat.... especially if errors happen so often...

Comment: I even downgraded Scons from 4 to 3 but no help there...

Comment: If you hop onto the SCons Discord server people can help you out a little more interactively. There's a link here: https://scons.org/contact.html

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that next

Answer (score 1):

Some old packages could be fixed with [2to3 tool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html), run it on old source folder then try to setup with python3. Another way is to install python2.